# How to Schedule meeting using skype for business Using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, skype-for-business

I need to schedule a meeting request with skype for business using c# , I need to include an skype for business URL in email to user. so clients can meet on that URL for their meetings.

I tried different options like UCWA by using postman . When ever i tried GET method with my domain name then i am getting error as response. Please find the below screenshot.[image]

I tried another c# sample application downloaded from https://github.com/ShelbyZ/UCWA.NET , When i make console project as startup project. it is having huge number of errors.

I need to know how to schedule meeting in skype and needs to found that meeting url for further usage. Can any body help me on this please.